# Visual Basic 6 GetTextBetween that that matches multiple criteria

Tags: vb6

I'm having an issue, I'm sure my title is off, but not sure how to word the issue.  I'm putting together a small tool that will look at serial console output in a textbox.  I want to look for files that are non zero size, and get the directory and filename added to a listbox.

My textbox output looks like this:

```
Directory of system:/

718  drwx           0                    <no date>  cme
2    -r--           0                    <no date>  default-running-config
725  dr-x           0                    <no date>  fpm
3    drwx           0                    <no date>  its
105  dr-x           0                    <no date>  memory
1    -rw-         867                    <no date>  running-config
104  dr-x           0                    <no date>  vfiles

No space information available
Directory of tmpsys:/

6   drw-           0                    <no date>  eem_lib_system
5   drw-           0                    <no date>  eem_lib_user
21  -rw-           0                    <no date>  eem_pnt_2
23  -rw-           0                    <no date>  eem_pnt_3
25  -rw-           0                    <no date>  eem_pnt_4

No space information available
Directory of flash:/

3  -rw-         822  Jan 27 2014 22:15:16 +00:00  TESTFILE1.TEST
4  -rw-         822  Jan 27 2014 22:15:22 +00:00  TESTFILE2.TEST
5  -rw-        1644  Jan 27 2014 22:15:30 +00:00  TESTFILE3.TEST
6  -rw-        2466  Jan 27 2014 22:15:38 +00:00  TESTFILE4.TEST
7  -rw-        4110  Jan 27 2014 22:15:48 +00:00  TESTFILE5.TEST
```

So far I have code that can find the non zero sized files, and list them in a list box, and I have code that can list the 'directory'  but I cant get both to work together.  Im using a function call GetEverythingBetween to find my files, here is that

```
Function GetEveryThingBetween(ByVal Str As String, ByVal strStart As String, ByVal strEnd As String, Optional ByVal st As Long = 0) As String()
Dim foundstr As String
Dim s1, s2 As String
Dim xStart As Integer
Dim xEnd As Integer
Dim bolKeepGoing As Boolean
Dim RetStr() As String
Dim StrCount As Integer

bolKeepGoing = True
s1 = InStr(st + 1, Str, strStart, vbTextCompare)
If s1 > 0 Then
    Do Until bolKeepGoing = False
    xStart = s1 + Len(strStart) + 1
    xEnd = InStr(xStart, Str, strEnd, vbTextCompare)
    If xEnd > 0 And xEnd > xStart Then
        'We have found an item
        foundstr = Mid(Str, xStart, xEnd - xStart)
        ReDim Preserve RetStr(StrCount)

        RetStr(StrCount) = foundstr
        StrCount = StrCount + 1
            s1 = InStr(xEnd + Len(strEnd), Str, strStart, vbTextCompare)
        If s1 < xStart Then
            bolKeepGoing = False
        End If
    Else
        'No more Items
        bolKeepGoing = False
    End If
Loop
End If
GetEveryThingBetween = RetStr

End Function
```

And then my code for finding the directories:

```
Dim Stuff() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim dir As String
On Error Resume Next


Stuff = GetEveryThingBetween(txtDisplay.Text, "Directory of", "/")
For i = 0 To UBound(Stuff)
dir = Stuff(i)

List1.AddItem dir

Next i
```

And then to find the files:

```
Dim Stuff() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim filename As String
On Error Resume Next

Stuff = GetEveryThingBetween(txtDisplay.Text, "        ", Chr(13))
For i = 0 To UBound(Stuff)
Exists = InStr(Stuff(i), "0") And InStr(Stuff(i), "<no date>") <> 0
filename = Stuff(i)
If Not Exists <> 0 Then List1.AddItem filename

Next i
```

I have tried to combine the 2 so that I have the directory then the file (if its non zero) added to the listbox, but it just loops and lists all the files again for each listed directory.   There is got to be a better way to get what I want, a listbox entry that looks like

"system:running-config"

My solution after working it out, kinda ugly, but works:

Basically splits it up into two parts. First it lists all directorys and then adds the directory to a listbox (disk0:, flash:, system: etc), then stats each dir by iterating through that list for files, collects the files and adds them to another lsitbox with the directory (list1 & filename), then clears the display, and goes on to the next directory in the list.

```
Dim Stuff() As String
Dim filename As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim Dir As String
Dim Exxists, Exists

On Error Resume Next
MSComm1.Output = "dir all" & Chr(13)

Do
DoEvents
Exists = InStr(Me.txtDisplay, "bytes free") <> 0
Pause 250
If Exists <> 0 Then GoTo NextStep
Loop   'let the dir command finish before issuing more commands

NextStep:
MSComm1.Output = Chr(13)
Pause 2000  'Add Directories to List1
Stuff = GetEveryThingBetween(txtDisplay.Text, "Directory of", "/")
For i = 0 To UBound(Stuff)
Dir = Stuff(i)
List1.AddItem Dir
Next i


txtDisplay.Text = ""  'clear dispaly

For z = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1  'Directory names in list 1
txtDisplay.Text = ""
Pause 250
MSComm1.Output = "dir " & List1.List(z) & ":" & Chr(13)  'displsys files in directory
Do
DoEvents
Exists = InStr(Me.txtDisplay, "bytes free") <> 0
Exxists = InStr(Me.txtDisplay, "No space") <> 0
Pause 250
If Exists Or Exxists <> 0 Then GoTo Step2
Loop  'wait for command to finish listing files

Step2:  'get the file names and add directory and file name to lsit2

Stuff = GetEveryThingBetween(txtDisplay.Text, "> ", Chr(13))
For ii = 0 To UBound(Stuff)
filename = Stuff(ii)
List2.AddItem List1.List(z) & filename
Next ii
Pause 1000
List1.RemoveItem (z)

Next z  'go to next directory name in list1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the input in one pass and determine which lines are directories and which lines are files. I used your `GetEveryThingBetween` method to parse out the directory names, but I had a problem with the file names so I added my own function for that. I think you can understand my `ParseDirOutput` method well enough that you can adapt it however you want.

```
Private Sub ParseDirOutput()
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim strDirMarker As String
    Dim strFileMarker As String
    Dim aryLines() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim strFile As String

    Dim stuff() As String

    List1.Clear
    strDirMarker = "Directory of"
    strFileMarker = "        "
    aryLines = Split(txtDisplay.Text, vbCrLf)
    For i = LBound(aryLines) To UBound(aryLines)
        strLine = aryLines(i)
        If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
            If InStr(strLine, strDirMarker) > 0 Then
                stuff = GetEveryThingBetween(strLine, strDirMarker, "/")
                strDirectory = stuff(LBound(stuff))
            ElseIf InStr(strLine, strFileMarker) > 0 Then
                strFile = ExtractFileName(strLine)
                If Len(strFile) > 0 Then
                    List1.AddItem strDirectory & strFile
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Function ExtractFileName(ByVal vString As String) As String
    Dim strReversed As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strReturn As String

    If InStr(vString, " 0 ") = 0 And InStr(vString, "<no date>") > 0 Then
        strReversed = StrReverse(vString)
        i = InStr(strReversed, " ")
        strReturn = Mid$(vString, Len(vString) - i + 2)
    End If

    ExtractFileName = strReturn

End Function
```

Comment: I liked this more then my solution, I posted mine to show my work as well, but this was educational for me.  Thank you.